# Adding extra multiple fields in Drupal(6.19) comment form

Tags: drupal-6, module, field, addition, comments

I am a complete novice to Drupal and module integration. I am given a task of letting the user give ratings in various ways along with their comment against a particular post. The rating will be 5 star rating. These rating will be for multiple fields such as Cleanliness(5 star rating), Communication(5 star rating) etc.

I have installed modules comment_cck, csm, token and fivestar. Just not able to put them together

How will i achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the fivestar module, you need to install voting API, and to build a view using the API, you need views.

Please follow [this screencast](http://www.lullabot.com/videos/building-views-fivestar-and-votingapi) - it should provide you with valuable info on how to use these modules. It's a little bit complex.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

How can i add multiple 5 star rating fields while the users are commenting. Voting API is already installed and is working fine. I need multiple instance for that star rating when the user is commenting.

Thanks,

Comment: Hah, to be honest, I've no idea what would work then :). The solution you found seems pretty solid, maybe you could combine it with the nodecomments module?

Comment: Thanks mate, nodecomments gave me the solution

Comment: Would you mind sharing it? I'm pretty curious about this one :).

Comment: the nodecomment module makes the comment a content-type, so i could easily add any number of fields to that content type(which basically is a comment node) using CCK :)